# If $4x/3y = 7/2$, what is the value of $y/x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $4x/3y = 7/2$, what is the value of $y/x$?

This is a multiple choice question, and the choices are as follows:

A. $3/14$

B. $8/21$

C. $21/8$

D. $14/3$

I started off answering this by cross multiplying it down to $8x=21y$

From there, $x=21y/8$ and $y=8x/21$

Therefore, $y/x = 64x/441y$. However I'm not sure how to get to a value answer. Where should I go from here?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: just multiply your equation by $\frac{3}{4}$ on both sides and ...... The answer is C

Comment: @KushalBhuyan I beg to differ.

Comment: @Bye_World ugh after that it was all remain to invert, which I hope OP will find out.

Comment: You correctly recognize that $x$ and $y$ are both numbers. Try to also see $y/x$ as a number, and also recognize that $y/x = \frac{1}{x/y}$.$$4x/3y = \frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{x}{y} = \frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{y}{x}} = \dots$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

multiply original equation by $3/4$ to get
$$
\frac{x}{y} = \frac{3}{4} \frac{7}{2} = \frac{21}{8}
$$
so inverting the fractions
$$
\frac{y}{x} = \frac{8}{21}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{4x}{3y}=\frac72$$

Then Multiply by $\frac{y}{x}$:

$$\frac{4x}{3y}\frac{y}{x}=\frac72\frac{y}{x}$$

Then:

$$\frac43=\frac72\frac{y}{x}$$

Then multiply by $\frac27$ to get...

Answer (score 3):

You were correct in reducing the original equation down to $8x=21y$. From here, similar to what you did, divide both sides by 21 and solve for $y$; namely, $$y=\frac{8x}{21}$$
Now divide both sides by $x$ to obtain your final result of $$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{8}{21}$$

Note: you could have just as easily obtained the result by first solving for $x$. I'll leave it up to you to figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

Take the equation:

$8x=21y$

Divide each side by $x$:

$8=\frac{21y}{x}$

Divide each side by $21$:

$\frac{8}{21}=\frac{y}{x}$